# Visual Studio 2017: js file causes many typescript errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, visual-studio-2017

**Please see the edit below**

I have used the following package as a base for my VS Project ->
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Everything worked nicely in Visual Studio code, I then tried to convert it to a Visual Studio 2017 Project (node.js web)

Now some problems appeared

VS seems to install TypeScript definitions into a special folder `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types`

Additionally I included  @types/node in my package.json which resulted in the appropriate node_modules folder.

now VS complains with error code TS4090 (Conflicting defintions for 'node').

Is there a possibility apart from deleting the folder in \AppData to tell VS which @types it should use?

The whole integration of TypeScript isn't really clear to me...
Does MSBuild recognize an existing tsconfig.json? or would I have to configure it in in the project-file [as seen here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html)?

**EDIT**

I just noticed that I was actually editing a .js file.
As soon as I changed the extension to .ts every warning and error vanished.
I also got many typescript errors (like TS2307, can't find module '@angular/core') before changing the extension from .js to .ts

The file just did an import (from node)

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

Could anyone explain why I got this errors?
Why a JS files causes 200+ typescript errors (some don't even seem related to the import from above)?

EDIT2
the errors which occur are

- TS2403 - Subsequent Variable declarations must have the same type.
- TS2300 - Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'
- TS4090 - Conflicting definitions for 'node' found (paraphrasing: found in `./node_modules` and `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types`

All the errors are caused by `d.ts` files in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.es6.d.ts`

like Bowden Kelly noted, this seems the cause for this problems seems to be the definition files MS put in here `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types`, as soon as I install my own definition files in `./node_modules` VS finds both definitions (if present) when editing JS files.
So the solution would either be:

- doing it the MS Way
- somehow exclude MS Directory

Comment: Both answers below did help but I had to choose one and I chose the one posted first.
But if you experience the same problem, see both answers.
(and than try to find a solution until you decide to go back to VS Code like I did...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition files installed to `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types` are used for giving JavaScript IntelliSense only. If you have TypeScript in your project or a project configured with a `tsconfig.json`, you need to fetch your own `.d.ts` files and store them in your project. Luckily this project comes with all the .d.ts files you need already in the `package.json` a simple `npm install` should do the trick.

I can tell you that the conflicting definitions with 'node' are likely due to having 2 copies of the node.d.ts file. If you manually installed one yourself, on top of the one included in the projects `package.json`, then you'll get those errors.

I'm not certain about the TS errors you are getting in your JavaScript file. Can you show me an example of one of the errors and a snippet of the code causing it?

Also you probably don't want integration with MSBuild as this project is already setup to run with npm scripts + webpack. You should check out this plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner

Finally I don't think you want to be inside a Node.js web project. For this project, you are probably best off just opening the folder in VS. To do that just use `File > Open > Folder...` and navigate to your root folder. This will give you all the editing tools you need without any MSBuild or VS project structure. Considering this project wasn't designed to take advantage of any of those features, it'll probably be easier just to ignore them for now.

Please let me know what other issues you run into.

Comment: that's interesting. I just checked it. When I use it as a JS File and jump to the definition of 'fs' I land in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types?`
But if I use it as a TS File I land in my ./node_modules/@types folder.

Is it possible to ignore the TypeScript\node_modules folder?

Unfortunately I can't provide any errors because they are currently not showing up...

Comment: As soon as I wrote my comment, the errors appeared. I edited my question with this new information.

Comment: Just to comment your suggestions:
I already tried to change my project so it integrates better with MS Build (I used NPM Task Runner) and I changed the project type to an empty ASP.NET Web Application.

But honestly, most if it felt just faster, cleaner and clearer with VS Code. The primary reason for trying the VS 2017 route was because I wanted to have Front- und Backen in one place (solution). 

VS 2017 does just to many things under the hood (like how are the @types every updated?)

Comment: To keep this alive because still having problems with Visual Studio TypeScript errors.  Here is a very simple project that causes bogus TS errors and corresponding GitHub issue that I wrote up (which has thus far not received any attention). https://github.com/jimbarrett33/VS2017_Typescript_Test https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15055.  Any help would be appreciated. I try to recommend/push Visual Studio for devs but it's hard to because these bogus errors reduce productivity by about 30%.

Answer (score 4):

This is a BUG related in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14565

I was able to eliminate the errors by enabling

[image]

Comment: Worked for VS 2022.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript, try to uncheck/disable the "new JavaScript language service" under `Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service`. This seemed to help me when I opened random JavaScript files and the error window would go crazy.

Regarding the Angular 2 errors (cannot find module @angular/core), if there is a tsconfig.json in the project directory both Visual Studio and the TS compiler will use that. If you close an reopen the solution everything on the TypeScript tab of project properties should be disabled.

Once you know tsconfig.json is working, if you are using TS 2.x the compiler should find and use the types that come with angular 2 under `node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts`, unless you have a setting in tsconfig that overrides this like `types: []`.

I have still not been able to figure out 100% what is going on in Visual Studio Errors window since I still get sporadic unjustified errors (I know this because I can still compile). I do know that the Visual Studio TypeScript Language Service is what controls errors and intellisense in the Visual Studio IDE and it is tied to a specific version of TypeScript (2.1 in VS 2017).  The errors have always caused problems in both VS 2015 and now VS 2017 also. I think it comes down to the inner workings of the extremely undocumented TypeScript Virtual Projects, for which I have still not found a purpose.

These links are useful reading:

http://blog.angular-university.io/typescript-2-type-system-how-do-type-definitions-work-in-npm-when-to-use-types-and-why-what-are-compiler-opt-in-types/

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14540

Comment: Disabling the Javascript Language Service seems to help (it sometimes takes a long time until errors are refreshed)

Comment: Yes, I have seen this also.  The errors will remain there and at some point disappear. Sometimes closing JS files in the solution will trigger them to disappear but not always. I wish I knew how to trigger the language service to do it's thing instead of waiting for whatever cycle it is on.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this has been fixed in Visual Studio 17.2

Comment: This should be a comment, which you will be able to add after gaining reputations.
Need not to add separate answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31753240)